# Use Angular-CLI or still use webpack for newer Angular 4 projects

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-cli

We have reached mid 2017 and frontend space has gone through a lot of upgrades and the most recent one being webpack adoption by Angular-cli. I am about to work on a new Angular 4 project. Before I start, I want to have an opinion from the community on which between the two (Webpack or Angular-CLI) should I adopt for my project and why?.

1. Have Angular-cli reached to a stage where it can be put into use for big projects or is yet evolving?
2. If I opt to go for Angular-Cli, is there anything that could pull me off later (limitations/features)?
3. Is Angular-cli docs proper and useful?

Comment: Well I have news for you. Angular-CLI runs Webpack to build and bundle all JavaScript and CSS code and comes with Webpack dev-server.

Comment: in addition to this question, I want to know whether we can use both together?

Comment: Be advised though that you cannot override the `webpack.config.js` in an Angular-CLI project. See this topic on github; 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1656 .

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

My original answer is below but outdated. Angular CLI now supports `webpack.config` via `ng eject`.

- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject

#### Original

1. Angular CLI uses Webpack to build / bundle project code.
2. Angular CLI does not currently support `webpack.config` ([and it doesn't look like they plan to anytime soon](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1656#issuecomment-239366723)), which could be a problem for your project down the line.
3. I don't see why you couldn't start with Angular CLI and then transition the project away from it over time. Angular CLI certainly makes scaffolding a project easier.